# Pentaho OLAP limit

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, olap

I have been working on multidimensional analysis with pentaho community. The problem is, when I do the aggregations and filters, I get in the output no more than 1000 records(rows). I want to know if am doing something wrong or pentaho analysis tool has a limitation. 
If so, does power BI community edition have a good limit ? Or can you suggest me another community tool to continue the work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Saiku for OLAP analysis?

For Saiku,  we have the limit in

TABLE_LAZY_SIZE = 1000 (default) Which you can change as per your requirement.

reference: http://saiku-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/saiku_settings.html